# In R, can you group intervals between events by length?

Tags: r, excel

The data I am working with has the time intervals between events that occur in groups (ie. 4 events with .1 to.2 seconds between them and then a 100 second pause before another group of 6 with .1 to .2 seconds between them). And at the end of the data frame it gives a large negative number that I need to discard.

An example data frame:

```
structure(list(Interval.1 = 0.1545, Interval.2 = 0.1605, Interval.3 = 0.1795, 
               Interval.4 = 3.7845, Interval.5 = 0.14, Interval.6 = 0.1735, 
               Interval.7 = 123.559, Interval.8 = 0.6245, Interval.9 = 0.1685, 
               Interval.10 = 0.1535, Interval.11 = 0.1935, Interval.12 = 1.408, 
               Interval.13 = 0.159, Interval.14 = 0.2375, Interval.15 = 0.162, 
               Interval.16 = 0.172, Interval.17 = 4.4575, Interval.18 = 0.1865, 
               Interval.19 = 0.1545, Interval.20 = 0.1795, Interval.21 = 0.151, 
               Interval.22 = -219.9355), class = "data.frame", row.names = "a25")
```

I've been attempting to find a way to analyze the average inter-event-interval in each group that way I can compare the traits of each group of events rather than the entire row of events (there are 100+ rows that I need to analyze in this manner, and I'm trying to see if there's variation between groups in the same row). As of now, I've been using excel and I've been able to find the average inter-event-interval of the entire row by averaging all values over 0 and under 1, but that doesn't allow me to compare the averages of the groups.

An example of the excel function I've been using:

```
=(SUMIF(B2:BI2,">0",B2:BI2)-SUMIF(B2:BI2,">1",B2:BI2))/(COUNTIF(B2:BI2,">0")-COUNTIF(B2:BI2,">1"))
```

Is there a way to calculate the averages of each group individually so I can compare groups within a row, and if so, how?

A solution in r is preferred, but an Excel function that could do the same thing would be helpful as an r solution is found. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have a full grasp of what you want, but I think this will put you in the right direction. First I gathered the data using tidyr, so it's long rather than wide. I then added a new column as a stand in for the number you were trying to average.  Then it comes to I think the key part of your question, how to group. I used cumsum to make a new group any time the cumulative intervals were above 1. (This is where I'm not entirely sure how you wanted to group them).

*Modified to include the comment request, of having a file with multiple datasets and keeping their grouping separate

```
dat<-data.frame(structure(list(Interval.1 = c(0.1545, 0.1345), Interval.2 = c(0.1605, 0.1205), Interval.3 = c(0.1795, 0.1195), 
                               Interval.4 = c(3.7845, 3.6845), Interval.5 = c(0.14, 0.12), Interval.6 = c(0.1735, 0.1235), 
                               Interval.7 = c(123.559, 130.559), Interval.8 = c(0.6245, 0.6145), Interval.9 = c(0.1685, 0.1145),
                               Interval.10 = c(0.1535, 0.1435), Interval.11 = c(0.1935, 0.1535), Interval.12 = c(1.408, 1.608),
                               Interval.13 = c(0.159, 0.139), Interval.14 = c(0.2375, 0.2325), Interval.15 = c(0.162, 0.167),
                               Interval.16 = c(0.172, 0.182), Interval.17 = c(4.4575, 4.4635), Interval.18 = c(0.1865, 0.1895),
                               Interval.19 = c(0.1545, 0.1595), Interval.20 = c(0.1795, 0.1725), Interval.21 = c(0.151, 0.121),
                               Interval.22 = c(-219.9355, -240.9355))
), row.names = c("a25","a26"))

dat$row_names<-row.names(dat) #Make row names to identify grouping

dat2<-dat%>%
  gather("key", "value", -row_names) #Gather to make the data long, rather than wide

dat2["NumberToAverage"] <- rnorm(1:nrow(dat2)) #Adding a number to average when grouped

dat3<-dat2%>%
  group_by(row_names)%>% #Group by row names to make the cumsum
  mutate("Group" = cumsum( value > 1))%>% #Creating a group, any time the cumulative sum is over 1, it adds a new group
  ungroup() #From my understanding it's good practice to always ungroup in case further modification of the dataframe is needed

head(dat3)
```

Output showing how the grouping looks:

```
 row_names key        value NumberToAverage Group
  <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>           <dbl> <int>
1 a25       Interval.1 0.154          1.75       0
2 a26       Interval.1 0.134          0.555      0
3 a25       Interval.2 0.160          0.586      0
4 a26       Interval.2 0.120         -0.415      0
5 a25       Interval.3 0.180          0.194      0
6 a26       Interval.3 0.120         -0.0161     0
```

And lastly, grouping to make an average and standard deviation:

```
dat3%>%
  group_by(row_names, Group)%>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(NumberToAverage), #Mean of the NumberToAverage by Group
            SD = sd(NumberToAverage))%>% #Standard deviation of the NumberToAverage by Group
  ungroup() #From my understanding it's good practice to always ungroup in case further modification of the dataframe is needed

   row_names Group    Mean    SD
   <chr>     <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a25           0  0.175  1.48 
 2 a25           1 -0.900  0.701
 3 a25           2  0.560  1.38 
 4 a25           3 -0.143  1.05 
 5 a25           4  0.983  1.09 
 6 a26           0 -0.264  1.00 
 7 a26           1  0.771  1.19 
 8 a26           2 -0.425  1.07 
 9 a26           3 -0.0933 1.08 
10 a26           4 -0.512  1.62
```

If you need to remove certain rows, such as that negative number, a simple dplyr piping of %>%filter(value > 0) would keep only rows above 0. Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: That sounds great! I think you have exactly what I wanted since the groups tend to have an interval of a second or more between them that should separate them out accurately. Thank you so much!

Comment: This might be a stretch, but is there a way to adapt this so it works on a csv file with multiple datasets in it? So it'd be multiple rows similar to the one I gave as an example, but I wouldn't want their groups to blend together since they're separate observations.

Comment: @Meridia - Modified the code, once again hoping this puts you on the right track!